# Python write function introducing capitalization to booleans

Tags: python, json, ajax, python-requests

I am gathering data from a json response, adding a handler and saving it to a data.jsonp file. From this .jsonp file I use AJAX to load the jsonp and display showtime details. Why is my format operation adding capitalization to boolean values in my jsonp file?

I've tested json.dump, but since I am using a .jsonp file with a handler, json.dump will save it as a string with "dataHandler[json-stuff]" instead of dataHandler[json-stuff]

```
# setting handler for jsonp and logging
callbackhandle="dataHandler"
handledmoviedata = '{callback}{json};'.format(
    callback=callbackhandle,
    json=moviedata.json()
    )
print(handledmoviedata)

# writing handledmoviedata to data.jsonp
file = open("data.jsonp","w")
file.write(handledmoviedata)
```

Expected output includes boolean values within the jsonp data. Instead, the boolean values have the first letter capitalized resulting in parsing error:
ReferenceError: True is not defined

If the boolean values are not capitalized, the script parses fine and displays showtimes correctly. I believe the issue has to do with .format as when I dug through the logged responses prior to adding the handler, the boolean values were not capitalized. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am still a beginner.

EDIT: I must have a callback handle at the beginning of my jsonp file, which is why I cannot use json.dump

ex: callback[{json-stuff}] NOT {json-stuff}

EDIT2: Here is the full Python script, API keys have been redacted for obvious reasons

```
from datetime import date
import requests
import json


# constructing the parameters for API GET request
moviefeedparams = {
    'startDate': date.today(),
    'zip': '94568',
    'radius': '2',
    'api_key': '*redacted*',
    'imageText': 'true',
    'imageSize': 'Md',
}
print(moviefeedparams) # logging parameters for debugging if needed


# making the GET request & logging for debugging
moviedata = requests.get('http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/movies/showings', params=moviefeedparams) # (assembled url
print(moviedata.json())

# setting handler for jsonp and logging
callbackhandle="dataHandler"
handledmoviedata = '{callback}{json};'.format(
    callback=callbackhandle,
    json=moviedata.json()
    )
print(handledmoviedata)

# writing data to data.jsonp
file = open("data.jsonp","w")
file.write(handledmoviedata)
```

EDIT3:
Result when using json.dump - "dataHandler[{json-stuff}]" with quotes and capitalized booleans
Result when using file.write - dataHandler[{json-stuff}] but booleans are capitalized
Result wanted - dataHandler[{json-stuff}]

The capitalization has something to do with .format, the booleans are not capitalized until I have run my data through .format

```
handledmoviedata = '{callback}{json};'.format(
    callback=callbackhandle,
    json=moviedata.json()
    )
```

Comment: What is `moviedata`? The `.json()` method of that object doesn't seem to produce valid `json`.

Comment: If `moviedata` is a dictionary, such as `{'name': 'Move Title', 'in_theaters': False}`, you can simply do `json.dumps(moviedata` which will convert a dictionary to valid json. Which will look like, `"{"name": "Movie Title", "in_theaters": false}"`. However unless we know exactly what `moviedata` is we can't really help you more than this.

Comment: moviedata is a dictionary response from the API, but I must wrap the response in a callback in order for my AJAX request to process correctly.
ex: callback[{json-stuff}] NOT {json-stuff}